# Plain Form of にくいです and とくいです

Tags: grammar

If I want to add から(because) to にくいです, would it become にくいだから　or にくいから
Also, if I want to add けれども to とくいです、is it とくいだけれども　or とくいけれども

Thank you!

Comment: These seem like homework questions. Has your class covered the difference between *i*-adjectives and *na*-adjectives? (Hopefully, I'm using the same terms that you are.)

Comment: When you say `にくいです`, do you mean 難い or 憎い?

Answer (score 2):

This is what we call a 「ひっかけ[問題]{もんだい}」, a catch question.

Even though 「にくい」 and 「とくい」 may look alike, each belongs to a different part of speech.  「にくい」 is a [形容詞]{けいようし} and 「とくい」, a [形容動詞]{けいようどうし}.  In the world of Japanese-as-a-foreign-language, however, I hear that the former is called an "i-adjective" and the latter, a "na-adjective".

**When attaching other words such as から、けれど、ので, etc. directly to these two types of "adjectives", an extra word must also be inserted with one of the two types.**

> ***I-adjectives vs. Na-adjectives:***

With 「から」:

> 「にくい + から」 vs. 「とくい + **だ** + から」　（「にくい**だ**から」 is incorrect.）
>
> 「おおきい + から」 vs. 「きれい + **だ** + から」

With 「けれども」:

> 「にくい + けれども」 vs. 「とくい + **だ** + けれども」
>
> 「かわいい + けれども」 vs. 「すてき + **だ** + けれども」

With 「ので」though you did not ask about it:

> 「にくい + ので」 vs. 「とくい + **な** + ので」
>
> 「ちいさい + ので」 vs. 「しずか + **な** + ので」